# Locate Memory Leak in Apache/PHP

Tags: php, apache, memory-leaks

I've got a website that is running LAMP.  On Saturday, the site crashed.  Turns out the hard drive on our dedicated server (4.5 years old) went south.  They replaced the drive (with updated OS (Cent 5.x if makes difference)) and I uploaded the code (that has been working perfectly for 4+ years) and restored the databases (thank god for backups!).

Suddenly the site periodically slows to a halt.  The support staff is reporting that Apache is running out of memory and it's killing performance.  I can see one of the apache threads monopolizing the memory (sometimes over 50%).

The system has a lot of source (too much to paste here for sure) so I don't even know where to begin to look.

One thing I *DID* notice is that I set up the server originally in Jan 2009.  The new hard drive is running PHP 5.3, which was not available then (I am presuming we were on 5.2, but of course I can't check any configurations...).  Is there some resource of what I might be able to check?

Any help appreciated. I am befuddled as to how an application running for 4+ years suddenly has drastic change by moving 1 version of PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Start digging through the [changelogs](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) and see if anything's applicable to your system.

Comment: This is something that belongs on serverfault

Comment: @MarcB - I did go through the change logs and I also went through the [migration documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php) but couldn't find anything.  Reducing the number of apache connections seems to have at least prolonged the problem, but I'd like to resolve it.

Comment: Just noticed another difference.  When I upload files, it uploads them with logged in user ID and group of psacln.

Comment: The original copy had owner:group of root:root. Is this a potential problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer...  I *THINK*.

After some investigation, I noticed that newly uploaded files were owned by <user>:psacln.  The original files (which were copied from a mounted drive for speed) were owned by root:root (who I was logged in as).

I changed the owner of the other files to <user>, but the problem didn't go away.  So I then changed the entire directory tree to <user>:psacln.  The site stopped working (gave unauthorized access error).  The sibling folders to the website root were all owned by <user>:psaserv.  So I changed the owner to <user>:psaserv (all the children underneath still owned by <user>:psacln) and it hasn't had a problem since.  It's been 2 days and as I monitor the processes, I noticed that occasionally one of the httpd processes (there are about 12) hits 1.5% of memory (When I was having the issues before, they would routinely hit 40%).

I am genuinely curious as to why this is the case (so I know how to avoid in future), but I am reluctant to spend much more time on it since it's now working just dandy.

Anyone has any ideas one the why's and wherefore's, I would love to hear it.  Hope this helps someone!